# Javascript execution order difference between linux and windows

Tags: javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee, dojo

```
function show_SelectRateItems() {
                document.getElementsByName("buttonval")[0].value="No";
                dojo.event.topic.publish("show_RateItems");
                setTimeout(show_SelectRateItems, 500);
                dojo.event.topic.publish("show_OhItems");
                setTimeout(show_SelectRateItems, 500);
                dojo.event.topic.publish("show_TaxItems");
                return false;
            }
```

Hi, Above mentioned is javascript method I execute to get output from 3 different methods for a single action (changing dropdown value). This is java web application. I am using ajax here. The problem is this executes fine in windows OS and gives me output to display in 3 separate locations. But when I hosted the war file for same in Ubuntu OS. Last one is not giving me output. Instead throwing error!

Comment: Every time you call `show_SelectRateItems`, it calls itself twice. Are you trying to fork bomb yourself?

Comment: hi Quentin,its "Error loading 'Ajx_TaxItems' (500 Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Why do you think its calling itself twice? I am not doing so?

Comment: 500 means the problem is with the server side code. Either it is just plain broken or it is failing to handle unexpected input cleanly. You need to look at the input and the server side code (and the error logs on the server to find out what the real error is)

Comment: Lines 4 and 6 both call `show_SelectRateItems`

Comment: methods called by dojo.event.topic.publish("show_OhItems") and dojo.event.topic.publish("show_TaxItems") is depended on output of dojo.event.topic.publish("show_RateItems"). But this was not consistent in windows earlier. So I was trying to put sleep before calling show_TaxItems and show_RateItems. Looks like I used a wrong method. What is the right way to put sleep before calling show_TaxItems and show_RateItems. Thanks for guidance.

Comment: To not. Use callbacks if you want to wait for something to happen.